# How can I get list of available place to post via LinkedInAPI (personal Page or company pages)

Tags: linkedin-api

A user on LinkedIn has his personal page and **his company/corporate pages** (which he manages, he has rights to post status updates on as well).

**How can I get a list of his company pages via LinkedIn API, so I can select which stream to post?**

(I am able to post to his personal page via API).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation: https://developers.linkedin.com/documents/company-lookup-api-and-fields

> You can also fetch a list of all companies the authenticated user is an administrator of

```
GET https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?is-company-admin=true
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<companies total="2">
  <company>
    <id>123456</id>
    <name>Test Company 1</name>
  </company>
  <company>
    <id>1337</id>
    <name>LinkedIn</name>
  </company>
</companies>
```